# Free array of function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If an array of function pointers is statically allocated, do I still need to `free()` it?
Lets say I have this code:

```
typedef void (*test_ptr)(void);

int main(void) 
{
    test_ptr test[3];
    test[0] = a;
    test[1] = b;
    test[2] = c;
}
```

So, when I would be done with it, would I have to free all the pointers, maybe like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    free(test[i]);
}
```

Or is it automatically de-allocated when function ends, like other arrays?

Comment: You should only free things you allocate, or where some function allocates for you (e.g. `strdup`). Since you didn't allocate anything for the array, why do you want to free it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, when I would be done with it, would I have to free all the pointers

No. You must not because `free(ptr)` is used only when pointer `ptr` is previously returned by any of `malloc` family functions.
Passing `free` a pointer to any other object (like a variable or array element) causes **undefined behaviour**.

#### C11: 7.22.3.3 The free function:

> [...] If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, **the behavior is undefined**.

---

> Or is it automatically de-allocated when function ends, like other arrays?

Yes. It will no longer exist once its enclosing function returns.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not!

An array allocated like that is located on the stack, and `free` will fail horribly if you try it.

As an aside, the array you show is *not* "static". I think you mean "local", or even "auto" (although that can be confused with a C++ concept).

Aside no. 2: allocation on the stack means that you should *not allocate large arrays* this way. The stack typically has limited capacity, so anything large should be allocated via `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic local variables like the ones in your case are destroyed as soon as the function in which they are created gets over. In your case, they will be destroyed when the `main()` function gets over.

So you don't have to explicitly `free()` those variables.

Comment: statically created variables are only destroyed at end-of-program.

Comment: and there are no statically created variables in the given code.

Comment: by statically i did not mean the variables created using `static` keyword. i meant the automatic variables whose memory is not allocated dynamically

Comment: There is no other meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Does that code own the pointed-to-object, and was it allocated with one of the allocation-functions corresponding to `free` (`malloc` `realloc` `calloc`)?

If so, `free` it at the end.

If not, desist.

You are clearly in the second case...